# Can I use Python's functools @cache based on identity?

Tags: python, caching, identity

I would like to have a Python `@cache` decorator based on identity, not `__hash__`/`__equal`.

That is to say, I would like the cached value for an argument `ka` NOT to be used for a different object `ka2`, even if `ka == ka2`.

Is there a way to do that?

In code:

```py
from functools import cache


class Key:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __eq__(self, another):
        print(f"__eq__ {self.value}, {another.value}")
        return another.value == self.value

    def __hash__(self):
        print(f"__hash__ {self.value}")
        return hash(self.value)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.value


i = 0


@cache
def foo(key):
    global i
    i += 1
    print(f"Computing foo({key}) = {i}")
    return i


ka = Key('a')
ka2 = Key('a')

print(f"foo(ka): {foo(ka)}")
print(f"foo(ka2): {foo(ka2)}")  # I would like the cached value for ka NOT to be used even though ka2 == ka.
```

Comment: Seems unusual. What do you want this for? Maybe there's a more normal solution?

Comment: Yes, it is a bit unusual. These are tables filled with values. Generally I want to compare the entire table (for tests mostly), sometimes I want to compare dicts with such tables as values (which requires the use of __eq__). But in a particular algorithm I need just identity (comparing the whole table there would be too expensive). I suppose I could write a function eq_values or some such and write an ad hoc function to compare dicts with eq_values, but at the end there will be some ad hoc somewhere, might as well be a cache_by_identity decorator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a wrapper like `Key` that compares by the identity of its wrapped object, and wrap your caching function in a helper that uses the wrapper:

```
class Id:
  __slots__="x",
  def __init__(self,x): self.x=x
  def __hash__(self): return id(self.x)
  def __eq__(self,o): return self.x is o.x

def cache_id(f):
  @functools.cache
  def id_f(i): return f(i.x)
  @functools.wraps(f)
  def call(x): return id_f(Id(x))
  return call

@cache_id
def foo(key): …
```

Comment: Seems like quite a bit of refactoring. How about a `cache_by_identity` drop-in replacement that can be used instead of `cache` (but internally it would do the things you're doing here)?

Comment: @KellyBundy: It’s one renaming plus two lines, but yes you could manufacture the helper functions inside a decorator.

Comment: Yes, it's not super much, at least if you only use it once, but such a decorator would still be nicer to use and reuse. I guess I'm trying to "spread the good word about software reusability and composability" :-P

Comment: @KellyBundy: I do hate redundancy, even if it’s hard to know whether this will get used repeatedly.